# Getting a vector with all the "TRUE" occurrences from a list in R language

Tags: r, list, vector

I'm doing text mining and i need a final vector (occurrences) to have one only TRUE for the words that appear on other vectors.
For instance:

From this vector `test = c("1","2","4","6")`

```
y = c("5","2")
x = c("3","2", "2", "4", "3", "1")
```

and the following list:

```
list_test = list(y ,x, "1")
```

I would need the occurrences to be:

```
print(occurrences)
TRUE TRUE TRUE

# but I'm getting 
> print(occurrences)
[1] TRUE TRUE
```

Where do I have the algorithm wrong?

```
test = c("1","2","4","6")
occurrences = c()
double_occurrences = c()
all_occurrences = c()

y = c("5","2")
x = c("3","2", "2", "4", "3", "1")

list_test = list(y ,x, "1")

for(comment_test in test){
  for(testword in list_test){    
    if (length(testword) > 1){
      for(i in 1: length(testword)){
        for (keyword in grepl(comment_test, testword[i], fixed=TRUE)){
          if (keyword == TRUE){
            double_occurrences = c(double_occurrences, keyword) 
          }
        }
      }
  } else {
    keyword = grepl(comment_test, testword, fixed=TRUE)
      if (keyword == TRUE){
        occurrences = c(occurrences, keyword) 
        }
      }
  }
  if((length(double_occurrences)) > 1){ # To several lists of words just ONE TRUE
    double_occurrences =  c(TRUE)
    all_occurrences = c(all_occurrences, double_occurrences)
    double_occurrences = c()
  }
}

occurrences = c(occurrences, all_occurrences)
print(occurrences)
```

the actual output is

```
print(occurrences)
TRUE TRUE
```

and expect to have

```
print(occurrences)
TRUE TRUE TRUE
```

Comment: i don't think your question is clear. in your intended output `TRUE TRUE TRUE` does each `TRUE` correspond to each of the tested vectors in `list_test`? i.e. if a letter from `test` occurs in the first element of `list_test` then `TRUE` is returned?

Comment: A `TRUE` value for each value of `test` that appears on `list_test`.

If a string of the vector `test` occurs in the elements of `list_test`, the `occurrences` should return a `TRUE` for each.  
For instance: The string "1" of vector `test` appears in `list_test` on vector `x` and also in  "1", then it should return a single `TRUE`. After the code, evaluates the string "2" and it appears on vector `y`, `x` so another single `TRUE` should be returned, and so on for the string "4".

Answer (score 1):

how about this:

```
test %in% unlist(list_test)
#[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

no need for `for` loops as the `%in%` operator is vectorised. the output is a boolean vector of the same length as `test`, each element of which is `TRUE` if the corresponding element in `test` features in `list_test`, and `FALSE` otherwise.